# How to simulate tactile sensor arrays with hydroelastic contact?

Tags: drake

I find the current Drake software framework does not support tactile sensor arrays. I would like to inquire if Drake plans to support tactile sensor arrays in the future. If users wish to implement this on their own, how should they proceed?